# Multiple triggers for a jquery-click-event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for that simple question, but how do I add multiple triggers to a `jquery-click-event`?

I tried that one here

```
$("#trigger1","#trigger2").click(function() {
    //something
});
```

But that doesn't work. What is the correct syntax there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working is you are using a context selector. So what it is saying is: Find #trigger2 and inside of that look for #trigger1.

But what you want is to use a [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$("#trigger1, #trigger2").click( ... )
```

Or I would just use a common class so you do not have to keep track of the ids

```
$(".commonClass").click( ... )
```

Answer (score 8):

Should be like :

```
$("#trigger1, #trigger2").click(function() {
    //Put your logic here
});
```

Just remove the extra quotes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or something like

```
$(document).on("click", "#trigger1, #trigger2, #trigger3", function () {
    //do stuff
});
```

This will let you add as many listeners as you want on multiple `DOM` elements